# How to align 2 tables (left and center) inside a div?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to center one table inside a div and have another table floating to the left of the first one.
My desired result would look something like this:

```
[ (Left Table)     (Center table)               ]
```

But with my current HTML and CSS (seen below) I get this result:

```
[ (Left Table)           (Center table)         ]
```

The problem here being that it floats the first table to the left and centers the second table in the remaining space.

**This is the code:**

```css
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#left {
  float:left;
}

#center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table id="left">
    <tr>
      <td>
        Left
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table id="center">
    <tr>
      <td>
        Center
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Any help on how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `position:absolute; left:0px;` for the first table and `position:relative;` for the wrapper

```css
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    position:relative;
   
}
#left {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    /*
    float:left;*/
}
#center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <table id="left" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>table1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="center" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>table2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked out perfectly. Been looking all over for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `#wrapper` to `position: relative;` and `#left` to `position: absolute; left: 0;`

```css
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: skyblue;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#left {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
#center {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table id="left">
    <tr>
      <td>Left Table</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="center">
    <tr>
      <td>Center Table</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.table-container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
table {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
}
.tbl2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class='table-container'>
  <table class='tbl1'>
    <td> Hello </td>
  </table>
  <table class='tbl2'>
    <td> Hello </td>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please attach some information on what the problem was and how you fixed it to the answer.

Comment: Since you have to set a table in left and another in center then you have to set at least one of the table position as absolute.
So, I set the absolute position for second table(center one), by setting its left position to calc(50% - 50px)